# Getting the Values from Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am going Round-Robin Algorithm. I am doing in that  everything must be created dynamically and Randomly. When I want to go second time to  check if I have and value the is more than 0 in the checking point it says that "The given key was not present in the dictionary". How can I Fix this problem.

```
private int GetNextNodeToProcesssRandom()
{
    int NextNodeIndex = -1;

    if (NextNodeToProcess >= this.waytosave.Count)
    {
        NextNodeToProcess = 0;
    }

    for (int i = NextNodeToProcess; i < this.waytosave.Count; i++)
    {
        if (this.waytosave[i] > 0)//the problem appears here when the cod goes for the second time.
        {
            NextNodeIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    NextNodeToProcess++;

    return NextNodeIndex;
}
```

Comment: Where are you populating your dictionary ??

Comment: So, the key wasn't present in the dictionary. Given the "randomness" why would you expect that it is? If you are trying to linearly index into the Dictionary, use `ElementAt` or just use a `List` instead.

Comment: Dictionary is not index based, it is key based. For me it looks like you're assuming it is index based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somehow unclear what is your exact goal. However if you want to loop through a Dict you can use:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> entry in MyDict)
{
    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
}
```

Now if you want to add a check in your program you can try:

```
    if (MyDict.ContainsKey(this.waytosave[i]))
///continue execution...
```

A look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might help you